# Can someone find $\vec{A}$ for this example [found in my TB : Griffith] with this method?

Tags: mathematical-physics, dirac-delta, electromagnetism, step-function

Example 10.2 of 3rd edition Griffith [electrodynamics]
[click here to read this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyMJr.png)

So I thought to convert I into $\vec{J}$ as follows :
$$\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)= I_o\theta(t)\delta(x)\delta(y)\hat{z}$$
Here $\theta(t)$ is [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $\delta(x)$ is just a [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
And now we know that as $\rho$ is assumed as zero. So $\phi=0$, and now we know that the formula for vector potential is $$\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\dfrac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int\int\int\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r'},t_{retarded})}{\mathfrak{r}}d\tau'$$
If we take the above integral and solve then it doesn't reduce to this:-
$$\vec{A}=\dfrac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\hat{z}\int{\frac{I}{\mathfrak{r}}dz}$$
as claimed by the author in the first step.
[click this to read the solution of the author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW2Jh.png)
. A small note for those might be familiar with electrodynamics. By 'I' I mean the electric current defined as $$I(t)\equiv\dfrac{d}{dt}q(t)$$ and here $$\vec{r}\equiv<x,y,z>$$  is position vector of any point in some given frame. Here $$\vec{r'}\equiv<x',y',z'>$$ be the position vector of the source charges and source currents. And let $$\vec{\mathfrak{r}}\equiv\vec{r}-\vec{r'}$$ be oistion vector defined with respect to the source point. And here $t_{retarted}\equiv t-\frac{\mathfrak{r}}{c}$

Comment: tried phys.stackexchange?

Comment: Thanks. Now I've also posted there as you suggested. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620530/can-someone-show-how-to-reduce-the-general-integral-of-veca-to-the-one-used